# Extract deep down data from JSON Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

```
{
  "hoodie": {
    "body": {
      "default": {
        "colors": {
          "style": {
            "solid": {
              "colors": {
                "body": "body"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "additional": {
        "logo": {
          "image": ""
        },
        "chest-pocket": {
          "colors": {
            "chest-pocket": "chest-pocket"
          }
        },
        "tag": {
          "image": ""
        }
      }
    },
    "sleeves": {
      "default": {
        "colors": {
          "style": {
            "solid": {
              "colors": {
                "sleeve": "sleeve"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "additional": {
        "cuffs": {
          "colors": {
            "cuffs": "cuffs"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The format in which I needed is to extract the additional keys. As in this case, hoodie key contains body and sleeves as its key which in the additional contains its different keys corresponding to the additional key. I have given the Object that needs to be parsed and the data obtained after parsing.

```
{
  "body": ["logo", "chest-pocket", "tag"],
  "sleeves": ["cuffs"]
}
```

Anyone can please share the link it might help me to play with Objects.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: aren't you missing the body after sleeves? sleeves: {body: ...

Comment: @Deeepanshu kindly accept the answer if it worked for you, so it will be helpful for others for future reference :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to get the desired output with the help of [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Kindly check the below snippet code.

```js
const input = {
  "hoodie": {
    "body": {
      "default": {
        "colors": {
          "style": {
            "solid": {
              "colors": {
                "body": "body"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "additional": {
        "logo": {
          "image": ""
        },
        "chest-pocket": {
          "colors": {
            "chest-pocket": "chest-pocket"
          }
        },
        "tag": {
          "image": ""
        }
      }
    },
    "sleeves": {
      "default": {
        "colors": {
          "style": {
            "solid": {
              "colors": {
                "sleeve": "sleeve"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "additional": {
        "cuffs": {
          "colors": {
            "cuffs": "cuffs"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

let output = Object.keys(input.hoodie).reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr] = Object.keys(input.hoodie[curr].additional)
return acc 
}, {})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding objects as trees, you need to iterate over property keys at different levels of the source object. If the paths to the subtrees of interest are fixed, select the respective subtrees and collect keys with the `Object.keys` method.

Specifically:

```
Object.keys(objSource).forEach ( (ps_key_toplevel) => {
    objTarget[ps_key_toplevel] = {};
    Object.keys(objSource[ps_key_toplevel]).forEach ( ( ps_key_parts ) => {
        objTarget[ps_key_toplevel][ps_key_parts] = Object.keys(objSource[ps_key_toplevel][ps_key_parts].additional);
    });
});
```

***Example***

Full-fledged mapping with the supplied data:

```js
    const objSource = 
      {
        "hoodie": {
          "body": {
            "default": {
              "colors": {
                "style": {
                  "solid": {
                    "colors": {
                      "body": "body"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "additional": {
              "logo": {
                "image": ""
              },
              "chest-pocket": {
                "colors": {
                  "chest-pocket": "chest-pocket"
                }
              },
              "tag": {
                "image": ""
              }
            }
          },
          "sleeves": {
            "default": {
              "colors": {
                "style": {
                  "solid": {
                    "colors": {
                      "sleeve": "sleeve"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "additional": {
              "cuffs": {
                "colors": {
                  "cuffs": "cuffs"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      };

    let objTarget = {}
      ;

    Object.keys(objSource).forEach ( (ps_key_toplevel) => {
        objTarget[ps_key_toplevel] = {};
        Object.keys(objSource[ps_key_toplevel]).forEach ( ( ps_key_parts ) => {
            objTarget[ps_key_toplevel][ps_key_parts] = Object.keys(objSource[ps_key_toplevel][ps_key_parts].additional);
        });
    });
    
    console.log ( objTarget );
```

Comment: It's not the same output as desired. there is no hoodie key that is required in my case. I've attached the desired output in my question. you can check it.

Comment: Yes, this code demonstrates how to obtain property key lists from different levels of a structured object. It's a trivial modification to get the object under 'hoodie' as a result (or to produce that subtree as a result in the first place). I'd place a bet that in any usage scenario beyond a toy example, the targeted result wouldn't be limited to a single item anyway ... ;)